# using vue custom element

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to use turn my vue app into a widget to use on external sites so basically I'm using https://github.com/karol-f/vue-custom-element
this to turn the app component into custom tag problem is my app have router and when I'm trying to use it on external website the parent URL some how get injected into my vue widget and this give me 404 not found page in my vue app how to solve this?

main.js file

```js
    import vueCustomElement from "vue-custom-element";
    Vue.use(vueCustomElement);
    App.store = store;
    App.router = router;
    Vue.customElement("vue-widget", App);
```

index.html

```html
    <body>
        <noscript>
            <strong>We're sorry but <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %> doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
        </noscript>
        <vue-widget></vue-widget>
        <!-- <div id="app"></div> -->
        <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
    </body>
```

Comment: Seems like you need to provide the correct base url for your widget. Maybe this will help you figuring it out: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations

Comment: @moritzgvt problem is not the base url cuse my app loads the the currect one but the rest of the url for example my external page is domainB.com/welcome and when im trying to load my widget in that page my vue app trying to get mydomain/welcome but that route wont exist

Comment: Have you tried https://vuidget.danajanoskova.sk/

Comment: @IVOGELOV this is exactly what im using

Comment: Then perhaps you already tried https://github.com/karol-f/vue-custom-element/issues/32 You may find this interesting, too - https://github.com/vuejs/vue-web-component-wrapper/issues/19